# Eclipse ADT facebook set up - Locating adb tool in platform tools

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, eclipse-adt

I am following

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/

And I am at step 2:

Secondly, locate the adb tool in the platform-tools directory of your main Android SDK. On OS X, you will have chosen this location when you unzipped the Android SDK. On Windows, the SDK is installed into your home directory, under AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

A lot of that language is really unclear and I am not sure what is meant by it, but on windows 7 if I system search I find no adb or platform-tools and I can't find it in android SDK either. Where is this tool and why can't I find it? I have eclipse adt installed and an emulator of a phone running but I can't find this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the directory you installed ADT to (the Android Developer Tools). There should be 2 folders in that folder, Eclipse and SDK. In SDK, there should be platform-tools, and in there should be adb.exe.

**Edit**: If you have an actual Android device (not the emulator) that you're testing your app on, you don't need to complete Step 2. You can just install the Facebook app via Google Play. If you're using an emulator to test your app, you still need to complete this step.

Comment: Ahh ok I found it now, I didn't realize main android SDK meant eclipse, I though it means the .android folder. Anyways what do I do with it now that I located it?

Comment: If you're testing on an emultator, you would start up the emulator, go into command prompt (cmd.exe), and navigate to that folder, and then run the commands shown on the tutorial.